# TFS2015: Test agents deployment through HTTPS failes: Access Denied

Tags: tfs, build, tfs-2015

I'm getting a bit strange situation with a 'Visual Studio Test Agent Deploment' in TFS2015 Update 2.1. When in Machine Group the protocol is set to HTTP everthing is ok, testagent deploys sucsefully. But when I'm trying to do the same task with HTTPS connection to remote machine i'm getting exception:

```
DistributedTests: Task 'DownloadTestAgent' on machine 'XYZ:5986' is being run
DistributedTests: Task 'DownloadTestAgent' on machine 'XYZ:5986' completed.

DistributedTests: Task 'DownloadTestAgent' for machine XYZ:5986's Error : System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: Connecting to remote server XYZ failed with the following error message :
Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

Machines are in the same domain. It's not a user/password problem because when I use HTTP it succesfully finishes the deployment, but when I edit 'Machine Group' to use HTTPS it failes.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you didn't configure HTTPS for WinRM on the host machine, you would need to follow the directions for [domain-joined machines](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm):

If you choose HTTPS, you can use either a FQDN or an IP address to access the target machine(s). To use a FQDN to access the target machine(s), execute the following in a Command window with Administrative permissions:

```
ConfigureWinRM.ps1 {FQDN} https
```

To use an IP address to access the target machine(s), execute the following in a Command window with Administrative permissions:

```
ConfigureWinRM.ps1 {ipaddress} https
```

> These commands create a test certificate by using MakeCert.exe, use
>   the certificate to create an HTTPS WinRM listener, and open port 5986
>   inbound for WinRM over HTTPS. The script also increases the WinRM
>   MaxEnvelopeSizekb setting. By default on Windows Server this is 500
>   KB, which can result in a "Request size exceeded the configured
>   MaxEnvelopeSize quota" error.